# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined because aysnc in script need to Remove render-blocking JavaScript:

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched my site on this https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/
it showed I have Render blocking javascript (jquery).. so I put  async

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" async></script>
```

after that I got the following error..

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

for the following jquery dependent code

```
$(function(){
    $('.SOMECLASS').on('click', function(){
       //some action
    })
})
```

So I changed to the following

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    $('.SOMECLASS').on('click', function(){
       //some action
    })
})
```

But still it is throwing the same error.
also tried

```
window.onload = function(event) { 
    $('.SOMECLASS').on('click', function(){
       //some action
    })
}
```

but it if add window.onload click functions doesn't work..

How to make the code run after jquery is loaded?

Please help me..

Comment: Is your javascript in the page itself, or also in an external script file?

Comment: Have you got the script tags for jQuery before the script that you're trying to run?

Comment: @Geoff Yes, but it's now `async`.

Comment: try put defer instead async

Comment: @James Thorpe yes it is in the same page, I have external script also

Comment: @ Avihay m bro defer is for external script.. here jquery is not doing anything.. dependent scripts are running before jquery being downloaded..

Comment: may be you can try by putting jquery script after the body and without async

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by "async" because jquery doesn't async support if you want async load then use jQI(http://www.yterium.net/jQl-an-asynchronous-jQuery-Loader) or requirejs javascript library.

Comment: Thank you bro my problem is I want to reduce render blocking scripts.. If I add your script I am afraid that it will also become another render blocking script.

Comment: I'm understand you but only use jQI or requirejs then other all javascript library on it load.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody in future come with the same problem.. I put all the jquery dependent code in the external script and called and make async and defer that solved it..